# How to print and format contents of a file onto a dialog box in PyGTK?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygtk

I'm struggling with this problem of printing the contents of file onto a new window when i click a menu option:

Following is the event handler :

```
def highscore_event(self, widget):
    app_window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    app_window.set_size_request(500, 100)
    app_window.set_title("Hall of Fame")


    hbox_b = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
    with open("highscore.txt", "r") as ins:
        halloffame = []
        for line in ins:

            app_window.add(hbox_b)
            label_b = gtk.Label(line)
            label_b.show()
            hbox_b.pack_start(label_b, False, False, 0)

    hbox_b.show()
    app_window.show()
```

The contents were printed as follows :
[image]

I tried formatting with "\n" but it still doesnt format it correctly. Is there any better way of doing this function in PyGTK or am i doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out. Change the hBox to vBox and it solved the error